# Magento 2.1: How can i add email to "New Invoice" template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates, order-email, address

I'm using Magento 2.1.2 for my ecommerce and trying to figure out how to add customer email to "New Invoice for Guest" and "New Order for Guest" email template.

Is there a way to add customer email address to those email templates? If not, is it possible to add it to "Address Templates" (System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates)?

I thought that it might be something like this:

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

or

`{{var email}}`

But can't get that to work. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone stumbles on this post again.

In CE 2.2.3, the following worked for me:

```
{{var order.getData('customer_email')}}
```

Comment: This also worked in 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> {{trans "%email,"
>   email=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}